# How to collate/nest nodes - Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have a graph schema

```
Album -[HasImage]-> Image.
```

I want to execute a cypher query that collates/denormalizes/nests/composes/whatevers the Images into the related Album.

I can get all the albums and all the images w/ a cypher query:

```
MATCH (a:Album)-[:HasImage]->(i:Image)
RETURN a, i
```

but the columnar format of the response is pretty annoying to handle. Is there any way to get the Images to be an array in the Album objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MATCH (a:Album)-[:HasImage]->(i:Image)
RETURN a, collect(i)
```

should do it

Comment: We must have answered at the same time. Funny how the act of writing a stack post is usually all it takes to figure something out.

Comment: Oh right, same time :-) Thank you for accepting my answer in that case

Answer (score 0):

Aha: **collect!**

```
MATCH (a:Album)-[:HasImage]->(image:Image)
RETURN a, collect(image) as images
```